# I am getting a ModelNotFoundError: No module named 'simpy' message in jupyter notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, simpy

Not sure what I am doing wrong. keep receiving this error related to no module named simpy to I can run some regression and other analysis. I attached a snippet of the jupyter notebook code to give context.

[Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ5sA.png)

Thank you for any help!

Jack

Comment: Did you mean sympy?  (symbolic python module used for doing algebra and calculus in python)    https://docs.sympy.org/latest/install.html

Answer (score 0):

That message usually means that simpy is not installed.
Did you try installing it via `pip install simpy`?